# Extracting dates from columns and sort them

Tags: r, date, timestamp

Dear colleagues I have the following dataset:

```
Time1                Signal1       Time2                Signal2           Time3                Signal 3
2018-05-06 17:41:44  Value 1       2018-05-06 17:32:39  Value 1           2018-05-07 00:06:00   .....
```

Time X columns are in POSIXct format, Because the time of the signals is different I am trying to make a custom resampling and I am trying to extract the timestamp of each signal.

I need to storage the time of each signal, putting this values in one vector and short this vector in ascending order.

I have try to:

```
NewTime<-sort(dataset[,c(1,3,5)])
Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing
```

Also with:

```
NewTime<-sort(unlist(Time_Trend[, c(1,3,5)]))
```

But with the last time I loose the date format, is there any way of doing this procedure without loosing the POSIXct format apart that having the vector in messy format.

Finally I have tried with this:

```
NewTime<-cbind(data$X1,data$X3, data$X5)
actualTime<-as.POSIXct(actualTime, origin="2018-05-06 07:50:32") #lowest value
```

But it returns me a vector with year date 2066. Anyone that has done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to `order` based on multiple columns

```
dataset[do.call(order, dataset[,c(1,3,5)]),]
```

---

If we are looking for creating a `vector` of datetime variables and then do the `sort`

```
sort(do.call(`c`, dataset[c(1, 3, 5)]))
```